# What is the best way to compute string similarity?

Tags: nlp

Consider you are given with two strings S1 and S2. What are the different algorithms available to compute how similar these strings in terms of their context and which one of them is the most efficient in terms of accuracy?

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use python, the most recent technology is word embedding. You can think of it as converting words to high-dimensional vectors (from 200 to 1000 dimensions) by training on millions of documents.

For example, if your string is "Human computer interaction", you would be looking for something like this.

```
[(2, 0.99844527), # The EPS user interface management system
(0, 0.99809301), # Human machine interface for lab abc computer applications
(3, 0.9865886), # System and human system engineering testing of EPS
(1, 0.93748635), # A survey of user opinion of computer system response time
(4, 0.90755945), # Relation of user perceived response time to error measurement
(8, 0.050041795), # Graph minors A survey
(7, -0.098794639), # Graph minors IV Widths of trees and well quasi ordering
(6, -0.1063926), # The intersection graph of paths in trees
(5, -0.12416792)] # The generation of random binary unordered trees
```

from: https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/tut3.html

Answer (score 0):

Try following algorithms:
Jaro–Winkler distance
Levenshtein distance these 2 algos are helpful for the string matching. It is depends on your string. According to string decide which is feasible for you.

Comment: Hey VinGol, thanks for the suggestions. From what I interpret, these algorithms work on the assumption that similar sentences will share the same words. Wouldn't these algorithms fails for the sentences like "Get me the latest tech news" and "what are the recent tech updates" although they tend to have a similar meaning